How to align selected bone roll to active bone with python
It seems Blender doesn't have this feature. However, I want to write to script to help rigging but I tried it and I am not good at it.

This is similar to what we wanted to do in this question. Consider the following situation:

We have two bones pointing in different directions. If we look down on the xz-plane of the selected bone (next figure), we'll realize that what we need is to rotate the bone around its y-axis to make the x-axis point in the direction of the green arrow.

If we look closely, we'll see that the green arrow seems to match the y-axis of the target bone. However, this is not exactly the case if we look at the following figure. The y-axis of the target bone is oriented outside the xz-plane of the selected bone. Thus, what we really want is to apply a rotation (to the selected bone) that expresses the rotation difference between the x-axis of the selected bone and the projected y-axis of the active bone (on the xz-plan of the selected bone).

The part of the code that does this is included in the for loop (which covers multiple selected bones) in the attached script. Note that we're working with the available APIs which require more steps than what I would've liked.
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

# The armature needs to be in edit mode
edit_bones = bpy.context.active_object.data.edit_bones

# Get the active bone (the target to rotate towards)
active_bone = edit_bones.active
# Get the remaining selected bones (the bones that will rotate)
selected_bones = [b for b in edit_bones if b.select == True and b != active_bone]

for b in selected_bones:
    # Find the projection of the target's y-axis in the bone's xz-plane
    x_proj = active_bone.y_axis.project(b.x_axis)
    z_proj = active_bone.y_axis.project(b.z_axis)
    active_bone_xz_proj = x_proj + z_proj
    
    # Calculate the required rotation to point the x-axis of the bone
    # towards the target bone (using the projected y-axis)
    rotation = b.x_axis.rotation_difference(active_bone_xz_proj)
    
    # Get the current location, rotation, and scale of the bone
    l, r, s = b.matrix.decompose()
    # Modify the rotation based on the calculate rotation
    r.rotate(rotation)   
    # Assign a new materix from the location, modified rotation, and scale
    b.matrix = Matrix.LocRotScale(l, r, s)

# Extra steps to update the viewport
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

